# Hugo giving theme error when I install a new theme

Tags: go, hugo

I am new to coding and web development and I recently started a web development course so I could create a website for an NGO for which I work. I was generally googling when I came across Hugo's web framework. I decided to install Hugo on Parrot OS. I installed Hugo using the following command on the terminal:

```
snap install hugo
```

After running the following code, Hugo installed and it worked successfully. I then decided to install a custom website theme from Hugo's website only. I came across the theme called "meghna-hugo".

I performed the following steps on the terminal:-

```
hugo new site mywebsite
cd mywebsite/themes
```

after entering the themes directory I git cloned the theme

```
git clone git@github.com:themefisher/meghna-hugo.git
```

After cloning the theme I entered the following command to enter the exampleSite folder of meghna-hugo

```
cd meghna-hugo/exampleSite
```

After entering this directory I cut and pasted all the things from the mentioned directory to the root directory of my website.
After replacing all the files with the meghna-hugo files I decided to start the hugo server locally

```
hugo server
```

But after running the Hugo command I encountered this error

```
Error: module "meghna-hugo" not found; either add it as a Hugo Module or store it in "/home".: module does not exist
```

I used the following websites for user friendly instructions as they were easy to follow and understand
https://oxforditaliansociety.org/blog/installation/ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKT-tztvIEU

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up your config file for Hugo to include your chosen theme?

Generally, you have to add something like  `theme = "THEME_DIRECTORY_NAME"` to your config.toml

So in your case:

```
theme = "meghna-hugo"
```

This is found on the [Hugo Docs - Quick Start](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/), as well as, your [theme docs](https://docs.gethugothemes.com/meghna/basic-configuration/)

Comment: So when I create a new site using Hugo the following files and directories are created automatically by Hugo:- archetypes, config.toml, content, data, layouts, static and themes. After git cloning the meghna-hugo, we are told to replace the files and directories with the one which meghna-hugo provides. Meghna-Hugo provides the following files and directories:- config.toml, content, data, i18n and static. I opened the .toml file of meghna-hugo and it did contain theme = "meghna-hugo"

Comment: Your question inspired me to write [Easy Way to Play With a Hugo Theme’s Example Site](https://www.ii.com/easy-way-play-with-hugo-theme-examplesite/)! Rather than using `hugo new site` and moving the `exampleSite` directory, please try following the eight steps in my new article. I tested these steps with the meghna-hugo theme and it worked for me. I hope this helps.

Comment: @nm Thank you so much for writing that. I had actually given hopes that it would ever work but thanks to your tutorial that theme is working as it should and I am not getting into any more issues.

Comment: @KaranCheema I'm happy to hear that my new article worked for you. Thank you for inspiring me to write it, good luck with Hugo!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The `themeDir` variable is not properly set in the config.toml file. It reads "../..", it should be the themes directory instead. Change it to:

```
themesDir = "themes"
```

This worked great for me.